# java string to char array and inverse leads to wrong result

Tags: java, string, char

I want to convert a String to a char [] to perform some bitwise operations on it.

My first approach was to use the java standard functions:

```
String foo = "123456789"
char [] bar = foo.toCharArray();
System.out.println(bar.toString); //output: [C@4263e7f8
```

So it seems that the data gets altered using this function.
If I do it all manually:

```
  String foo = "123456789"
  char [] bar = new char[foo.length()];
  for (int i=0; i< foo.length(); i++) {
     bar[i]=foo.charAt(i);
  }

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i=0; i< bar.length; i++) {
     sb.append(bar[i]);
 }

 System.out.println(sb.toString); //output: 123456789
```

My question is why I get different data when I use the standard functions. I was expecting that I always get the same data after .toCharArray followed by .toString. I'm not sure how a Java String is represented bitwise. May this be a reason?

Comment: You are calling the toString method of the type char array. That uses the default implementation. The result is correct, but don't just go sop(myArray); that 'll land you results you don't want/expect. StringBuilder on the other hand, has an implementation of toString, which gets you the result you want.

Comment: thank you for all your answers - I can't vote "answer" yet. I wasn't expecting different implementations of the same function.

Comment: Each class has it's own implementation of toString. is it not implemented in the class itself, it takes the implementation from it's super class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you try to print an array by using `toString()`, it will print `hashcode` instead of printing the contents. Because:

> Java arrays are objects and the direct superclass of an array type is
>   Object.

Therefore when you are trying to call `toString` method, it will directly call Object's toString method which is:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

But when you are using `StringBuilder` class `toString()`, it will return a `String` object :

```
return new String(value, 0, count);
```

Answer (score 7):

In the first code snippet, bar is an `array object`.  So when you are trying to print the object, it prints it `hashcode`

If you use the same logic that building up a string from the `char` array after bar got created using `toCharArray()`, you could see the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`foo.toCharArray()` doesn't alter the data. If you want to get the original String back, you should call `new String(bar)`.

Calling `toString()` on an array executes the default implementation of `toString` method in `Object` class, which shows the class name (for `char` arrays it shows `[C`) and the `hashCode` of the instance.

If you want to display the characters of that array, use `Arrays.toString(bar)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bar)); //to print the result in list form
System.out.println(new String(bar)); //to print the result as a string
```

In `JAVA`, `arrays`are `objects`that are dynamically created and may be assigned to variables of type `Object`. All methods of class `Object`may be invoked on an array.

When you invoke `toString()` on an object it returns a string that "textually represents" the object. Because an array is an instance of Object that is why you only get the name of the class, the @ and a hex value.